# Как, после выполненного HttpWebRequest HTTPS запроса, сразу закрывать SSL туннель, чтоб он больше не использовался?

Tags: c#

Как, после выполненного HttpWebRequest HTTPS запроса, сразу закрывать SSL туннель, чтоб он больше не использовался?
То есть под каждый HTTPS запрос всегда создавался свой SSL туннель.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что оно работает иначе?

Comment: `KeepAlive = false` должно помочь